# When and how to remove ubiquitous lily of the valley

Tags: fall-gardening

We have a lot of lily of the valley acting as a sort of ground-cover in parts of our yard. It's never been our favorite and came that way with the house.  We just got a puppy who eats everything and anything, and since lily of the valley is so toxic, we think we should remove it so we don't have to constantly worry about him being near that part of the yard.

When is the best time to remove it, and what is the best technique for removing it?